# How to choose when to make a subquery in SQL / where to put it (in Select, From, or Where)?

Tags: sql, subquery

Beginner here. I am not trying to solve a specific problem at the moment. I've just seen that nested queries are used in Select statements as well as under the From and Where statements. What is the logic behind putting the subquery at different locations in the main query?

I understand that Select, Where, and From have different purposes but how would one just automatically know to make a subquery in the Where instead of Select or From? I suppose there are multiple ways of approaching problems, so is it the case that one could make a subquery in multiple locations and get the same answer?

Comment: Your question is very vague, there's no real way to answer it.  Try phrasing it with a specific scenario, example table structures / data or a scenario in a real world example which is easily extrapolated by people like.... how do you find the restaurants in a certain set of cuisine categories which are open now and have a rating of 3 or higher?

Comment: I see, yeah my question is a general one.

Comment: And, as such.... only a vague answer will work...  Don't worry too much about when to do what. If you follow the principles 1: Make it work, 2: Make it right, 3: Make it Fast.... you can't go to wrong.  Focus on making something work first.  Make it do what you need it to do in whatever way makes sense.  As you do that, you'll learn, and as you learn you'll figure out how to make it better, and better, and better.  THEN you can figure out how to make it FAST... that's where the true polish happens.